# mysqli query to search through an entire database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I read some answers that said to use the search option on phpMyAdmin to look for a certain string in all tables of a database. I tried to use the query executed by phpMyAdmin to look for the string in a php script. I kept getting fatal error as the query took more than 30 seconds to execute. The code I used is:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `classification`.`class` WHERE (CONVERT(`phylum_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%enteropneusta%' OR CONVERT(`subphylum_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%enteropneusta%' OR CONVERT(`superclass_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%enteropneusta%' OR CONVERT(`class_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%enteropneusta%' OR CONVERT(`class_name` USING utf8) LIKE '%enteropneusta%')";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
while($result){
 print_r($result);
}
```

need help again! I managed to come up with this query on the query builder of phpmyadmin

```
SELECT
* FROM
`table1`,
`table2`,
`table3`,
`table4`,...
`table12`,
  WHERE
(
    (
        `table1`.`columnlast` LIKE '%string%'
    ) OR(
        `table2`.`columnlast' LIKE '%string%'
    ) OR(
        `table3`.`columnlast` LIKE '%string%'
    )...

    ) OR(
        `table12`.`columnlast` LIKE '%string%'
    )
```

This takes more than 3-4 minutes to run. Is there any way to shorten the time?

Comment: If you have to spike in that many `CONVERT` calls you've got some encoding issues you need to fix for this to have any hope of running quickly. Secondly, `LIKE` is always going to be slow when used in substring more (`%...%`). Use `EXPLAIN` on your query to find out more.

Comment: what I need is a mysqli query to search through a database for a string. I couldn't find one (very little knowledge of mysql). If it is possible to search through the entire database without any of those `CONVERT` calls, please suggest a way. @tadman

Comment: If you store the data in UTF-8, query in UTF-8, and *everything* is UTF-8, then the `CONVERT` calls are extraneous.

Comment: @tadman I've updated the question with more details. Could you help?

Comment: A) This is a whole new question. Don't amend your existing questions with entirely new problems, create new questions. B) That query is a mess and will take forever to run since it has to scan the entire table multiple times now. Use a full-text search index, or something like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co).

Comment: my professor who was busy these days finally helped me. Will answer the question. Sorry about adding the new part. Thanks for all your help @tadman

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways to extend the execution timeout, in the php.ini file you can set max_execution_time, http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

On an individual page you can put

```
set_time_limit(240);
```

at the top with the number of seconds as the parameter.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find what you said: [php search page](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=max+execution+time&scope=quickref)

Comment: I've added some more detail to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, my professor who had been busy with his own project finally managed to free up some time to help me out and this is the query we used.

```
SELECT columnName1 as result FROM tableName1 WHERE columnName1 LIKE '%string%' 
UNION SELECT columnName2 FROM tableName2 WHERE columnName2 LIKE '%string% UNION
...
UNION
SELECT columnName12 as result FROM tableName12 WHERE columnName12 LIKE '%string%'
```